# Three random errors with Xamain.iOS project

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an old Xamarin.iOS project that shows up three random errors from nowhere.

[image: Three errors with Xamarin.ios]

These errors started appearing after Xcode 14, before that project was always working smoothly. I have tried almost everything including changing the deployment target for XCode, but nothing seems to work. If I had rolled back to the old commit, they would go away, but not anymore.

I would really appreciate it if someone had a solution to this problem.

Comment: First, there the latest **beta** of Xcode is 14.5.  I don't know how you think you're running 15.  Second, please do not post code or errors as images.

Comment: Typo, duly corrected. Thx

Comment: Have you tried deleting bin and obj folders?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try to update the dependency packages and the visual studio?

Comment: I've done everything from upgrading packages to updating VS and XCode. Nothing working